# Procastination when moving from c# code to html/css/jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I find when I writing non UI code on a project  I can be relatively productive (working in a top down manner from the service layer), following a TDD approach, Im nearly always out of the debugger until integration, not perfect but happy enough. FYI, I work in C# with R# enabled in VS2008.

However when I switch to stick a web interface over something, Im terribly bad in hitting F5 making a few changes here and there in css/html, changing famfam icons, debugging in firebug, adding more jquery etc, etc. FYI, I work in ASP.Net where controller delegate most out to the service layer, using Viewmodels dedicated to the Views etc.. generally following clean mvc.  Code in controllers is not TDD as I found its basically proxying to the service layer with a little mapping to/from viewmodels/formmodels so I've skipped over this portion.

Do developers that reach into the jquery/html/css area often have any tips to increase productivity and avoid procasination (e.g. here on SO now). This could equally apply to Java developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

debugger != procrastination - when you're doing graphical stuff, you need to keep viewing the output.

Testing GUIs to conform with a spec is a known hard problem, and for most cases it's not worth the pain - human eye pattern matching is superior.

If you are designing distinct, specified behaviour with jquery, it is possible to do TDD to some extent - there is testing framework called QUnit.  Have a look at [Getting Started With jQuery QUnit for Client-Side Javascript Testing](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2008/08/28/getting-started-with-jquery-qunit-for-client-side-javascript-testing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works better than strong coffee and Firebug with Firefox.
Now even IE with reaching there with IE8.

I think most of the css/html thing should be delegated to the web designers, where build the frame for developer's to put the data objects into.

Comment: Depends if you are the designer and the developer (and likely tester etc) at the same time... not everyone has the luxury of working in one area of web development.

Comment: Yep I agree Firebug is critical. Unfortunately I can't outsource some projects due to costs and company decisions, to be fair I can do jquery and semantic HTML layout etc.. but yikes i could be tweaking a toolbar for half a day.